# The election was set against the backdrop of wwII

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*set*".  According to definition 2 for the verb "set" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/set):

> 2. to cause the action of (a film, story, etc.) to happen in a certain place or during a certain time — often used as (be) set

, with these example usages:

> -The play is set in Verona, Italy.
>   -The novel is set in 1943.
>   -a novel set during World War II
>   -The story is set against (the backdrop of) the Second World War.

But then, I saw this in a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1944):

> The election was ***set*** against the backdrop of World War II, which was going well for the United States and its Allies.

The 1944 presidential is not a play or movie or story.  So, is the usage in the wikipedia article wrong?

Comment: It's a bit of a metaphorical usage.  Note that the definition doesn't say that the thing has to be *literally* a play or movie.

Comment: Why don't you try to find out what are the actual ways that native speakers abbreviate *World War II?*

Answer (score 3):

What bigger drama can you imagine than an American presidential election?

Seriously, the writer of the Wikipedia article uses the term **set** to present an image of the election as a theatrical production: the use of the word **backdrop** reinforces this image.

The writer is simply using a little artistic license.

Answer (score 3):

The play is set in Denmark. But that is not the definition of **set**  that is used here in the collocation **set against**. The collocation is not referring to a locale.The word **against** is important.  The one thing is placed *in an arrangement* where the "backdrop" acts as a **foil**, so to speak.

The underlying idea is  *juxtaposition* or *contextualization*.